# Pasar 2 parametros de pagina anterior mediante href en asp.net blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

Estoy enviando 2 parametros mediante un link por href de esta forma

```
 class="btn btn-primary" id="bton2" href="/detallefechas/@fecha1/@fecha2" role="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>
```

y recibo en la pagina de esta manera

```
 @page "/detallefechas/{fecha1}/{fecha2}"
```

al darle click al boton para que se envien estos parametros me arroja este error

> InvalidOperationException: Object of type
>   'MonitorSKC_Garantias.Pages.DetalleFechas' has a property matching the
>   name 'fecha2', but it does not have [ParameterAttribute] or
>   [CascadingParameterAttribute] applied.

esto me explica que estoy recibiendo el primer valor pero no el segundo
de que forma puedo recibir estos 2 parámetros sin que me de error?
Muchas gracias de antemano si es que alguien puede ayudarme.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Los dos parámetros necesitan el atributo `Parameter` del *build-in* de *Blazor*.

```
@page "/detallefechas/{fecha1}/{fecha2}"

<!-- ... -->

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Fecha1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Fecha2 { get; set; }

}
```

También convendría que comprobaras los nulos en el método `OnInitialized`, para evitar problemas.

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Fecha1 = Fecha1 ?? "Valor por defecto F1...";
    Fecha2 = Fecha2 ?? "Valor por defecto F2...";
}
```

Pero que sirva

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el componente **NavLink**.

```
<NavLink href="my-page?params">My page</NavLink>
```

---

O prueba con el evento **onclick**.

```
 @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ButtonClick">Click me</button>

@code {

    private void ButtonClick()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/my-page?params", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta anterior de VRoxa:

Cuando pasas parámetros por URL, estos se transfieren como string. Por lo cual los parámetros que recibís son string, **no formato fecha** como podría ser que los estas tomando, y por eso se da el error.

En ese caso deberías tomar los parámetros y transformarlos al tipo que necesites. Ademas, deberías ver que el formato cuando mandas no tenga algún carácter especial como por ejemplo: `"/"`. Ya que así nunca va a llegar a la URL que quieres.